# How to implement Back Navigation using JSPs

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp page that is divided in to two panels left and right. The let panel contains some links. When the user clicks on any link, a particular jsp/web page is loaded into the right panel. Now, I want to implement a functionality of back navigation. Meaning when i hit my browser's back button, the page that was previously loaded into the right panel, should be loaded again. Right now, if i hit the back button, i am navigated away from my current page.

Comment: This sounds more like an Ajax issue than JSP. You're loading the panel with Ajax right?

Comment: i am using something like $("#rightpanel").load(menulink, function() {});

Comment: i make this call in the onclick() function of the link